# How to combine output of multiple echo statements in a bash script to output them as a single line on standard output

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a script that will upload a file via rest api. I am trying to show the action and its completion using echo statements as below..

```
echo "Uploading file ..."  
curl -s -u user:pass -XPUT https://mywebsite/api/filename  
echo "DONE."
```

I want the standard o/p to look like as below.

```
Uploading file ... DONE.
```

Is this possible using echo?

Comment: You really did some thorough investigation by yourself before asking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group commands in curly braces and redirect the output for the whole command group:

```sh
{
  printf '%s' 'Uploading file ...'
  if curl -s -u user:pass -XPUT https://mywebsite/api/filename
  then outcome='DONE'
  else outcome='FAILED'
  fi
  printf ' %s.\n' "$outcome"
} >>logfile
```

Here, `printf` is used rather than `echo` to print the the `'Uploading file ...'` text without a newline character, and the `'DONE.'` text with an explicit newline.

Answer (score 0):

multiple commands are combine able using semicolon at the end of command as shown in below example

```
echo -e "Hello Kali " ; echo "Hello Debian" ; echo "Hello Arch"
```

and to store its output on a variable kindly cover commands with parentheses as shown in below example.

```
a=$(echo -e "Hello Kali " ; echo "Hello Debian" ; echo "Hello  arch") ; echo $a
```

now kindly use your commands as per the requirement.